# Bottom scrollbar

Tags: css, menu, scrollbar

i have a question.Why am i getting this bottom scrollbar?Cant really understand.I know that i can remove it but i cant even understand why it apears.
Hlp needed.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBjqxr

-HTML

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <div id="menuToggle">
    <!--
    A fake / hidden checkbox is used as click reciever,
    so you can use the :checked selector on it.
    -->
    <input type="checkbox" />

    <!--
    Some spans to act as a hamburger.

    They are acting like a real hamburger,
    not that McDonalds stuff.
    -->
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    <!--
    Too bad the menu has to be inside of the button
    but hey, it's pure CSS magic.
    -->
    <ul id="menu">
      <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>About</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Info</li></a>
      <a href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
      <a href="https://erikterwan.com/" target="_blank"><li>Show me more</li></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

-CSS

```
body
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /* make it look decent enough */
  background: #232323;
  color: #cdcdcd;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", "Avenir", sans-serif;
}

a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #232323;

  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

a:hover
{
  color: tomato;
}

#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;

  z-index: 1;

  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#menuToggle input
{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: -5px;

  cursor: pointer;

  opacity: 0; /* hide this */
  z-index: 2; /* and place it over the hamburger */

  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

/*
 * Just a quick hamburger
 */
#menuToggle span
{
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  position: relative;

  background: #cdcdcd;
  border-radius: 3px;

  z-index: 1;

  transform-origin: 4px 0px;

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              background 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0),
              opacity 0.55s ease;
}

#menuToggle span:first-child
{
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}

#menuToggle span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}

/* 
 * Transform all the slices of hamburger
 * into a crossmark.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-2px, -1px);
  background: #232323;
}

/*
 * But let's hide the middle one.
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(3)
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.2, 0.2);
}

/*
 * Ohyeah and the last one should go the other direction
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ span:nth-last-child(2)
{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0, -1px);
}

/*
 * Make this absolute positioned
 * at the top left of the screen
 */
#menu
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -50px;
  padding: 50px;
  padding-top: 125px;

  background: #ededed;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* to stop flickering of text in safari */

  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);

  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.77,0.2,0.05,1.0);
}

#menu li
{
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/*
 * And let's fade it in from the left
 */
#menuToggle input:checked ~ ul
{
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: `#menuToggle{...left: 50px; }` shifts everything over by `50px`; If you add `border: 1px solid white;` to `#menuToggle` you can see how it pushes over.

Comment: Changing the menutoggle to `position: absolute` seems to work in your codepen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `position: relative;` and `left: 50px;` on `#menuToggle`. That pushes `#menuToggle` 50px to the right, outside of the window. You can use margins on that element instead. Remove `top, left` and add `margin: 50px 0 0 50px;` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdGYyw

Answer (score 3):

Because you set

```
left: 50px;
```

with `#menuToggle`.
Since it is a relative positioned element it displaces the div with 50pxs, and creates a scrollbar. 
Replace left:50px; with margin-left:50px and it should fix your problem:

```
#menuToggle
{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;    
  z-index: 1;    
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` element will remove the scrollbar.

I would remove `left: 50px;` from `#menuToggle`, and add `padding-left: 50px;` to `#menuToggle input` and `#menuToggle` to avoid the scrollbar showing up in the first place.

Comment: OP knows how to remove it but wants to know why it appears.

Answer (score 0):

You should use position absolute instead of relative.

```
position: absolute
```